# TinyMCE is not working for mobile view in Google Chrome using "tinymce-rails" gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tinymce-rails

I have added "gem 'tinymce-rails'" in my rails application
I have added "//= require tinymce-jquery" in my application.js

And in my js.erb file, I initialized it using

```
tinyMCE.init({
  selector: '#offer_description',
  menubar: false,
  branding: false,
  height: 300
});
```

and on edit, I reinitialized it using

```
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true, (tinymce.EditorManager.activeEditor != null) ? tinymce.EditorManager.activeEditor.id : null);

tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor',true, (tinymce.EditorManager.activeEditor != null) ? tinymce.EditorManager.activeEditor.id : null);
```

And in my view page, I have added class "tinymce" like this:-

```
= form.text_area :description, :maxlength => "5000", :class => "listing_description_textarea tinymce"
```

It is working fine in both firefox and google chrome.
But in mobile view in Google Chrome, it is displaying a black box having a book icon in middle and the text area is not working.
There is no error in the browser console and Ubuntu Terminal.
What should I do to get it work properly?

[This error is displaying in mobile view in place of tinymce Text Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7yfM.png)

Comment: I think you might need [tinyMCE mobile](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/mobile/). Here is another question with the same issue as the one you described: https://community.tiny.cloud/communityQuestion?id=9066100000097myAAA

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.